# knuthBendix algorithm cannot be parallelized by Control.Parallel?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, parallel-processing, knuth

I am trying to apply knuthBendix to large sets of rewriting rules. Thus, I try to let it work on different sets in parallel.

As en example, I try to run:

```
import Control.Parallel
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import Math.Algebra.Group.StringRewriting

knuthBendixOptimized rs = as' `par` bs' `pseq` as' ++ bs' where
    (as, bs) = splitAt 3000 rs
    as' = knuthBendix as
    bs' = knuthBendix bs
```

I compile using `ghc -threaded` and I execute via `+RTS -N`. If I run other algorithms in parallel, it works. But for knuthBendix, it does not.

Does someone know a solution?

Thanks,
Franz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you're calling `` as' `pseq` ``. This evaluates `as'` to WHNF, which means that it only determines whether the list is empty or not. But you want the lists to be fully evaluated:

```
import Control.Parallel.Strategies    

forceList :: [a] -> [a]
forceList = withStrategy (evalList rseq)
-- or use rdeepseq to force the evaluation of everything

knuthBendixOptimized rs =        forceList as'
                          `par`  forceList bs'
                          `pseq` as' ++ bs'
  where
    (as, bs) = splitAt 3000 rs
    as' = knuthBendix as
    bs' = knuthBendix bs
```

<sub>Note that Haskell's usual term for this is *parallelism*. And *concurrency* is used for explicit work in `IO` with threads and their communication. See [the GHC manual](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/lang-parallel.html).</sub>

Comment: thanks! I think, you are right. I will test it tomorrow ... by the way: what is the verb related to parallelism. (Sorry for my english ;)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think `knuthBendix` parallelizes naively like that. The documentation says:

```
knuthBendix :: Ord a => [([a], [a])] -> [([a], [a])]

Implementation of the Knuth-Bendix algorithm. Given a list of relations, return a
confluent rewrite system. The algorithm is not guaranteed to terminate.
```

It seems to me that splitting up the way you've done will change semantics. You probably need some more invasive parallelism.

Comment: you are right. However, it should be possible to execute knuthBendix on subsets and then on the entire list. This is not my point. The question that I have is, why `as'` and `bs'` are not computed in parallel ...

Comment: @user2583983 You mean _parallelize_?